# XlsxWriter chart.add_series() and list of non-contiguous ranges

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

In my program I have two functions: first one calculates parameters of data to plotted and second one draws the chart. Problem is that when the data ranges are non-contiguous I cant't make "list of values" notation to work. [The Documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html) says non-contiguous ranges are supported but only gives example of 'category/value formula' notation. Any suggestions?

Drawing function:

```
def draw_chart(values,categories, type, name):
    chart = workbook.add_chart({"type": type})
    chart.add_series({
                "categories": categories,
                "values": values,   
                })
    chart.set_title({
                'name': name,
                'name_font': {
                'name': 'Calibri',
                'color': 'black',
                },
            }) worksheet.insert_chart("V"+str(categories[1]),chart)
```

Comment: For a non-contiguous range you will have to use the string range format like `=Sheet1!$A$1,Sheet1!$A$5,Sheet1!$A$8`. You cannot use the list format for this.